# BarChart3D lighting for negative values

Tags: plotting

I'm using `BarChart3D` to plot matrices. The code I wrote used to work fine until Mathematica 11.

For some reason, negative values of the matrix appear very dark on the plot, whereas it didn't before. It looks like, rendering speaking, the face normals switch direction when the bars are negative, and the lighting is thus reversed.

Example code:

```
BarChart3D[Table[1 Exp[-(((x - 4)^2 + (y - 4)^2)/8)] (x - 4), {x, 1, 8}, {y, 1,8}], ChartLayout -> "Grid", ChartElementFunction -> "Cube", Method ->{"Canvas" -> None}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False,ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{-1, Red}, {0, White}, {1, Red}}, #] &),BarSpacing -> {0, 0}, ViewPoint -> {-6, -9, 4.2},ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 850]
```

Comparison between 11.01 and 10.4:

[image: Comparison]
I found some ways around it by fiddling with `Lighting->{...}`, but it never looks as good as it used to.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome. Wait a few minutes that one of our users will leave some tips.

Comment: Quite strange that all the other chart functions from ChartElementData["BarChart3D"], such as FadingCube, work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct about the face normals switching direction, it seems that in version 11 we must be careful that `pt1` is lower than `pt2` in `Cuboid[pt1, pt2]`. Cuboids may appear inside-out if this is not the case. Example:

```
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Red, Green],
  Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}], 
  Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, -1}]}]
```

[image]

The bar chart can therefore be fixed by post-processing the `CuboidBox` boxes to meet the new requirement.

```
fix = CuboidBox[data__] :> RuleCondition[CuboidBox @@ Transpose[Sort /@ Transpose[{data}]]]

BarChart3D[
  Table[1 Exp[-(((x - 4)^2 + (y - 4)^2)/8)] (x - 4), {x, 1, 8}, {y, 1, 8}],
  ChartLayout -> "Grid", ChartElementFunction -> "Cube", 
  Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{-1, Red}, {0, White}, {1, Red}}, #] &), 
  BarSpacing -> {0, 0}, ViewPoint -> {-6, -9, 4.2}, 
  ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 850] /. fix
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot !